# How to get control(s) from TabPage in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have few TabPages and each contains rich text box. How can I access richtechbox on a selected tab?

```
TabPage selectedTab = tabControl.SelectedTab;
RichTextBox selectedRtb = selectedTab.Controls.Find("rtb", true).First() as RichTextBox;
```

This is what I have tried but no luck.

**Added:**

This is how tabpage is added with richtextbox control

```
TabPage newTab = new TabPage(name);
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
rtb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
rtb.Text = file.Data;
newTab.Controls.Add(rtb);
tabControl.TabPages.Add(newTab);
tabControl.SelectedTab = newTab;
```

Comment: Post the code that added the control to the tab.

Comment: The variable name is irrelevant.  You forgot to set the Name property.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is WinForms, it would just be:

```
if (selectedTab.Controls.ContainsKey("rtb"))
  RichTextBox selectedRtb = (RichTextBox)selectedTab.Controls["rtb"];
```

if rtb is the name of the RichTextBox control.

When creating your control, add the name to it:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.Name = "rtb";
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason your approach is not working is because your are trying to find it by using the control's name property.

Looking at your code you are not setting the `Name` property.  If you can generate a known name ahead of time you can use that when looking for the control.

You can also try this:

```
var rtb = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => x is RichTextBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Philip Fourie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11123/philip-fourie) answer is pretty good, made me realize that you can actually have the Design generating or not a name for the control.

[image: GenerateMember in Design]

Somehow, I got the GenerateMember set to false, once turning it back on I could access the control directly by it's name.