# How to get child control?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, tabcontrol

I have TabControl that contain 4 subTabs.

[image]

Each of the tab contain picture box cotrol.

I need to get the picture box control of the selected Tab Control.

Any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps

```
var picBox = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the control via

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.90%29.aspx

Once you find the control, you can then cast it to what you are expecting example:

[2] [How to get control(s) from TabPage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351462/how-to-get-controls-from-tabpage-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
var pictureBox = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => x is PictureBox);
```